# Why can't PlayOnLinux find the xterm on 18.04?

Tags: playonlinux, xterm

So I am trying to install PlayOnLinux with the terminal using these commands.

```
$ wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
OK
$ sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_bionic.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
--2020-04-21 21:48:13--  http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_bionic.list
Resolving deb.playonlinux.com (deb.playonlinux.com)... 51.254.83.230, 2001:41d0:2:37ca::1e
Connecting to deb.playonlinux.com (deb.playonlinux.com)|51.254.83.230|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 44
Saving to: ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list’

/etc/apt/sources.li 100%[===================>]      44  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-04-21 21:48:13 (4.60 MB/s) - ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list’ saved [44/44]

$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                     
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:3 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.playonlinux.com bionic InRelease                              
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Reading package lists... Done                                               
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:68 and /etc/apt/sources.list:74
$ sudo apt-get install xterm playonlinux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xterm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xterm' has no installation candidate
```

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, so I would appreciate some step by step assistance with this issue.

Comment: Why do you need `xterm` ?

Comment: It says I should install it to use PlayOnLinux, @Liso.

Comment: Says who ? The official [doesn't say so](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html).

Comment: Maybe it's a glitch, but I'd prefer have installed because it isn't really working the games I installed, @Liso.

Comment: Try `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xterm`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Bionic version

Type the following commands:

```
 wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -


 sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_bionic.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Or use the following command to directly download the package and install

```
 wget https://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.3.4/PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb

  chmod 777 PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb

  sudo dpkg -i PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb
```